# Change html text based on node.js server setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How would one change the text of a div to another string of text after a certain period of time using node.js and the setTimeout function?

The main caveat is that the text should be changed for all users at the same time.

Let's say an h2 title on the index page would initially say "Welcome to this page."

5 seconds later (after the **server** time, not after the time of a request), that h2 title should change to "Let's get started."

If another request came in 6 seconds after the server started, they should see "Let's get started." and never see "Welcome to this page." since the h2 title should have been universally changed.

Any guidance hugely appreciated.

Comment: As of the sixth second, does the text from previous requests that changed to "Let's get started" one second ago change back? If not, then not all clients are seeing the same thing. If so, do you really think they're going to notice the change and read the text in a second?

Comment: Why don't you just create some kind of global variable which is modified by setTimeout after 5 seconds. Whenever you render a page, you read the value of that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you may try (Express + SocketIO 1.0 example):

**server.js:**

```
var app    = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

var dir = __dirname;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(dir + '/index.html');
});

var header = 'Welcome to this page.';
setTimeout(function() {
    header = 'Let\'s get started.';
    io.emit('change_header', {
        header: header
    });
}, 5000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('change_header', {
        header: header
    });
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('change_header', function(data) {
        document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = data.header;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h2 id="header"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```